# How to read values from Worksheet and check their existence in a .txt file

Tags: excel, powershell

Using Powershell, I need to loop through each cell of a column and check to see if that value exists in another loop through of .txt files, in any of the files then populate an additional column(s) in the spreadsheet indicating which .txt files contain the value(s)

So far, I have a Powershell script which looks through a set of files from a selected destination. The script allows you to choose filename and extension and content. This part is good because I want to be able to loop through a selection of files, but I want the $SearchText value that it looks for in the files, to be looped through, changing one by one to each value in column A of a Worksheet I have in Excel. Once it finds the value in any of the selected files that are being looped through, it'll add a column to the Worksheet giving the file name it has been found in. If it's found in more than one file, it'll add columns for each it finds.

```
clear;
$Files = "";
$FileNameEnds = "";
$FileExt = ".txt";
$SearchText = "";



Foreach ($file in [System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles($Files,"*"+"$FileNameEnds."+$FileExt, [System.IO.SearchOption]::AllDirectories))
{
    $Textfile = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines($file);
    $FileContains = $false;

    foreach ($line in $Textfile.Split([System.Environment]::NewLine))
    {
        if($line.Contains($SearchText))
        {            
            $FileContains = $true;
        }
    }

    if ($FileContains)
    {
        Write-Host "Contains:" $file;
        Write-Host $FileContains
    }    
}

Write-Host "Done";
```

I want a successful double loop, one for setting the $SearchText value to each of the cells in a column from an Excel Worksheet I have, one by one, then use that value to search through a loop of files in a given destination, which is the bit I already have code for.

Comment: Welcome as a new user to [SO]. Please take the [tour] and also read [ASK]. SO isn't a free script writing service nor a forum, but a site for programmers helping colleagues who got stuck with a distinct problem. Own research and serious coding attempts are expected. There are plenty of examples here to open an excel file as a COM object and iterate columns/rows.

Comment: BTW searching through txt files is easier using Select-String. Depending on the number of rows it might also be more efficient to go the other way around, read the strings to search for and use only one run trough the files using select-string with a RegEx with alternations.